# Android: Round Swipable images

Tags: android, swipe

I want to implement a swipable round images in android, there will be once round image in the center and the same round images queued up behind the center image towards left and right sides.
The images in front overlap the images behind.

On swiping to right the image behind(towards the right) should come forward and the same vise versa as in case of left.

Can any one kindly help me figure out a solution for this.
Thanks,

Comment: Search for JazzViewPager its what you are looking for.

Comment: yes, JazzViewPager is what I was looking for

Comment: Good to hear that! Please vote up my answer if you find it useful :)

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look at this project, let me know if this is what you are trying

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/androcarousel.aspx